# angular ng-table pagination with async data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am trying to follow this ngTable pagination example

```
 $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
})
```

I'm having issues with the `total: data.length` attribute, since I'm getting this array from a server, via rest, my array length is 0 at start. I can set it to a static value, but that only works after I click somewhere on the page, and if my array were to get bigger than that value I would lose items.

The example i'm following is [here](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/1-1)

Can I accomplish pagination some other way, or can I update the data.length value somehow?

Comment: Research angularjs databinding and $scope.$apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the api call in `getData` and set the `total` property as such:

```
params.total(data.length);
```

This [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpPRgJ?editors=101) might help.

Answer (score 1):

In **getData** method, make an API call to fetch the data and once you receive the data in success callback, resolve the promise and set the total argument like this:

```
//set the table params total value
params.total(data.length);
// set new data
$defer.resolve(data);
```